# how to post headers.authorization value in db node api

Tags: angularjs, node.js, token

I am creating and set the user token in cookie at the time of loggin. and checking user authorization in API like below:

```
 apiRoutes.get('/authentication',function(req, res) {
  var token=getToken(req.headers);  
  if(token){
    var decode=jwt.decode(token, config.secret); 
    User.findOne({name:decode.name}, function(err, user){
      if(err){res.json(err)}
        if(!user){
          return res.send({success:false, msg:'Authentication Failed'})
        }else{
          res.json(user);
        }
    })
  }else{
    return res.json({success:false, msg:'No Token Found'})
  } 
  });

getToken = function (headers) { 
if (headers && headers.authorization) { 
return headers.authorization; 
} else { 
return null; 
} 
};
```

and in angular

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $cookieStore, $http){
    if($cookieStore.get('token') ){
        $rootScope.token=$cookieStore.get('token'); 
  }
  var token = $cookieStore.get('token') ;
    console.log(token)
    $http.get('/api/authentication',{ headers: {authorization:token }}).success(function(res){
        $rootScope.CurrentUser=res; 
    })
});
```

by this I am able to get logged user's all value.
But now I want to post the  Current  user's id in db through another API.
my another api is :

```
apiRoutes.post('/createlead', function(req, res){ 
var token=req.header.authorization;
var owner=jwt.decode(token, config.secret); 
  var createLead=new Lead({
    name:req.body.name,
    email:req.body.email,
    query:req.body.query,
    ownerId:owner
  });
  createLead.save(function(err, data){
    if(err){res.json(err)}
      else{
        res.json(data);
        console.log(data);
      }
  });
});
```

But in this `/createlead` api `token` is undefined..
Please help to post Current user's id in DB while posting some data.

thanks

Comment: How you posting data to `/createlead` - how are you adding headers when you calling `$http.post()`?

Comment: in `/createlead` i am using `.save` function......... I am creating and adding headers at the time of user login.

Comment: You are adding headers only when for request when user is login into. You should consider to call `$http.defaults.headers.common.authorization = token` according to AngularJS documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers

Comment: U mean I have to add headers in app.run?

Comment: `app.run(function($rootScope, $cookieStore, $http){

    if($cookieStore.get('token') ){
        $rootScope.token=$cookieStore.get('token'); 
         $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = $rootScope.token;
  }
  var token = $cookieStore.get('token') ;
    console.log(token)
    $http.get('/api/authentication',{ headers: {authorization:token }}).success(function(res){
        $rootScope.CurrentUser=res; 
    })
});
`

Comment: `app.run` is to early as you don't know token yet. When you calling API to login user - set that parameter there.

Comment: Can u please show me how to do that... ?

Comment: From where you have token? From what API?

Comment: token is creating in the `login` api... and I am decoding its and passing to angular in `/authorization` api .